# Python grid_forget

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to ask for your help regarding this.

I'm trying to clear a frame then adding new elements in it. However, after clearing all the elements, adding new elements do not show. Can please shed some light regarding my problem. Thanks

Here's my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Tkinter as tk
import socket
import sys

def next(line, num):
    s.send(line)
    data= s.recv(size)
    num.set(data)

class Client(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.configHost()

    def configHost(self):
        self.hostEntry = tk.Entry(self, justify=tk.CENTER);
        self.hostLabel = tk.Label(self, text='Host')
        self.connectButton = tk.Button(self, text='Connect', command=lambda:self.startServe())

        self.hostLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, ipadx=10, ipady=10)
        self.hostEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=4, pady=20, padx=20, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        self.connectButton.grid(column=2,pady=10)

    def startServe(self):
        hostnum = self.hostEntry.get()
        port = 50000
        size = 1024
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((hostnum,port))

        if s >= 0:
            self.grid_forget()
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, master=None)
            self.grid()     
            self.nowServingLabel= tk.Label(self, text="Sample") 
            self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Connect')
            self.nowServingLabel.grid()
            self.button.grid()
```

Comment: You shouldn't name a function `next` as it is a built in python function.

Comment: ok, noted. I shall rename it to nextCustomer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it is *highly* unusual to call the frame constructor more than once. Most likely that is the root of your problem. I have no idea what that does under the covers, but classes simply aren't designed to work that way.

Also, are you aware that grid_forget only removes a widget from view, it doesn't destroy it? If you keep "forgetting" and recreating widgets, you're creating a memory leak.